# Как с помощью win32com.client создать excel файл с нужным именем и в нужной папке?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

Нужно создать экселевский файл с названием вида 'report_2020.11.24_23.10.xlxs' в текущем рабочем каталоге используя win32com.client. Нижеследующий код падает с ошибкой **AttributeError: Property 'Add.Name' can not be set.**

```
import win32com.client

excel_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel_app.Visible = True
excel_workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Add()
excel_workbook.Name = 'report_2020.01.01_23.10.xlsx'
excel_worksheet = excel_workbook.Worksheets.Add()
excel_worksheet.Name = 'sheet title'
excel_workbook.Save()
excel_workbook.Close()
excel_app.Quit()
```

Если закомментировать строку excel_workbook.Name = ..., то код отрабатывает корректно, и листу присваивается нужное имя, но книга создается в 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Документы'. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пофиксить эти проблемы?
P.S.: win32.com использую из-за ещё возможностей работы с VBA. Других библиотек, которые предлагают такое я  не нашел.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO! Не только win32com будет ругаться на `.Name = ...,`, даже родной экселевский VBA на такой строке пишет разные нехорошие слова. Дело в том, что такое свойство у рабочей книги есть, но оно "read-only" - имя создаётся при сохранении книги в файл и поменяется только при пересохранении в другой файл. Так что выход прост - использовать не `excel_workbook.Save()`, а  `excel_workbook.SaveAs(<путь и ИМЯ файла>)`

Comment: Спасибо вам, добрый человек!!! Всё работает как надо)))